# Dividing two dataframe columns by each other, avoiding ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a dataframe with some statistics. One is called "Aerial duels" and the other "Aerial duels won". I want to divide aerial duels won by total aerial duels to get the win percentage. However, when I try to divide the columns I kept getting a ZeroDivisionError. This is not an issue of my pandas version, because for some reason when I try to do a mini demo I do get a series returned with inf values in place of the zero division. I've now tried to apply a lambda function, but then I get a KeyError: "Aerial duels". I can't figure out what the issue is.

```
numerator_name = "Aerial duels won"
denominator_name = "Aerial duels"
ser_stat_values = df_competitions[[numerator_name, denominator_name]].apply(lambda x: x[numerator_name] / x[denominator_name] if x[denominator_name] != 0 else 0]
print(ser_stat_values)

KeyError: 'Aerial duels'
```

Comment: The error means that it does not find column 'Aerial duels'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `axis` parameter to 1:

```
numerator_name = "Aerial duels won"
denominator_name = "Aerial duels"
ser_stat_values = df_competitions[[numerator_name, denominator_name]].apply(lambda x: x[numerator_name] / x[denominator_name] if x[denominator_name] != 0 else 0, axis=1)
print(ser_stat_values)
```

Comment: That does it, thank you!